# How to setup LavaPay extension for Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, payment-methods

I want to setup LavaPay extension for Magento, I install the extension I add the ID but I don't know what I need to do next.

I have this URL: https://www.lavapay.com/en/developers/sci/index.html

and here is the extension for Magento: [https://www.lavapay.com/en/developers/shop-systems/magento/index.html](https://www.lavapay.com/en/developers/shop-systems/magneto/index.html)

I create movie to understand how is look the error: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDnjYyh90a

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to activate it... Check system->configuration->paymetn methods if there you have new payment type for this lavapay. And probably you will need to test it trough some sandbox or?

If you already have active payment and you don't see it on frontend maybe you need to clear cache?

Comment: thank you for your answer, Is activated i see it on the checkout page, but it make a redirection to an url and I got this error:
Payment Error
Invalid or expired payment link.

Comment: I don;t know if the extension send datas to the lavapay website, and i don;t know how to find this, you see the extension? can you tell me a url? where i can see the send data?

Comment: You can check that with some firebug or just pres F12 in chrome, and then you need to check post prams which was posted to payment gateway. Maybe you miss some data in the url... Check that and maybe you will get the answer...

Comment: The post data is ok, i see there all data and all is send to the the lavapay.com site

Comment: Huh,.... You can try to post data with correct URL to gateway trough fiddler maybe and you will see the response... And the other option is to contact lavapay directly and they will tell you where the problem is.. Hope that you solve this problem. But like I said... Take the url and posted data and try post it with fiddler.

Comment: Hi thank you, please take a loo here https://jsfiddle.net/c7bn2yrh/ this is the post data. I contact the Lavapay support for a few times, but they don't want to answer. First they tell me that I have Magento 1.9.0.2 and the extension is build on Magento 1.7.0.2, i install Magento 1.7.0.2 on my server i install the extension is the same thing, i contact the support again, no answer. They have a very usefull support, for that i try to solve it here. Thank you anyway for your hep

Comment: i edit my post and i add a printscreen with post data ...

Comment: Ok I see the posted data... But I can not help you because I don't have merchant id... Hope that you change domain.com with accessible domain. I check their docs and I posted that url.. And I recive Merchant not found, so probably if you try to insert your merchant id for test into example url that is in their docs, just to see if it is going trough... Otherwise I have no idea what's the problem, probably you will need to wait to support answer your question. Wish you good luck with resolving this issue.

Comment: is there any way to talk in private i can send you the correct data

Comment: I change my public profile here, please take a look About me section, there is my email address, please send me an email and I will send you the correct data there. Is ok?

Comment: are you here? Can I send you email?

Comment: Did you receive some response from techincal support? I don't think I can help you further because i don't know anything about this payment. Sorry man just think that it is better to contact their support or just wait for them to reply on your support ticket.